# Correct way of inverting Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#

```
  public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Active<TEntity>(DateTime effectiveDate)
            where TEntity : IValidFromTo
        {
            return e => (e.EffectiveFrom == null || e.EffectiveFrom.Value.Date <= effectiveDate.Date) &&
                        (e.EffectiveTo == null || e.EffectiveTo.Value.Date > effectiveDate.Date);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>Inactive<TEntity>(DateTime effectiveDate) where TEntity : IValidFromTo
        {
            var isActive = Active<TEntity>(effectiveDate);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Not(isActive.Body), isActive.Parameters[0]);
        }
    }

    public interface IValidFromTo
    {
        public DateTime? EffectiveFrom { get; }
        public DateTime? EffectiveTo { get; }
    }

    public class Product: IValidFromTo
    {
        public Product(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        private int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EffectiveFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EffectiveTo { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var products = new List<Product>()
            {
                new Product(1){ EffectiveFrom =DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1),EffectiveTo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)},
                new Product(2){ EffectiveFrom = DateTime.Now.Date, EffectiveTo=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
                new Product(3){ EffectiveFrom =DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(1), EffectiveTo = null},
            };

    var activeExpression = PredicateBuilder.Active<Product> 
       (DateTime.Now.Date).Compile();
            var activeProducts= products.Where(activeExpression).ToList();

     `var inactiveExpression = PredicateBuilder.Inactive<Product> 
    (DateTime.Now.Date).Compile();
            var inactiveProducts= products.Where(inactiveExpression ).ToList();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

This code works fine. My question was raised when I use`(!)` to get inactive products instead of creating `Inactive()` method.

If you code for inactiveProducts as:
 `var incativeProducts= products.Where(PredicateBuilder.Active<Product>(DateTime.Now.Date).Compile()!).ToList();` compiler does not  complain about the (!) but the result is the same as `activeProducts`. Basically `(!)` does not do inversion in that context.

Is this expected outcome? Or what would be the correct way of inverting the Active without having a method like above?

Comment: Can you reduce code example to only significant to the question parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var incativeProducts = products
    .Where(PredicateBuilder.Active<Product>(DateTime.Now.Date).Compile()!)
    .ToList();
```

`!` in that context does not mean "not", it's a C# 8 feature that means that the nullable returned by `Compile()` is expected by you to not be `null`. If you want to negate an expression, the unary `!` operator sits, like every other unary operator, at the beginning:

```
var incativeProducts = products
    .Where(w => !PredicateBuilder.Active<Product>(DateTime.Now.Date).Compile()(w))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Not part of the question, but your code is extremely inefficient as written, it's calling both `DateTime.Now` and `Expression<>.Compile()` **for every single item in your source collection**. Compile the expression before calling `Where` with it.

Comment: also tried this compile exception'Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Expression<Func<ContractCLIVersion, bool>>' I get.

Comment: You probably didn't notice the lambda parameter in my `Where` call, show the code that you tried.

Comment: Yes you are right!.I indeed ignored `(w)` part. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest I am still not convinced with this. Not sure which one to use. Inactive is more self explanatory then using  `w => !PredicateBuilder.Active<Product>(DateTime.Now.Date).Compile()(w)`. Which one would you use? In terms of performance which one would be more efficient or both would be the same?

Comment: I recommend the Code Review site for this, but if you're asking about performance, having `Inactive` will need a separate compilation, which obviously uses memory and processing power to actually generate the IL and then JIT compile it. Plus it's not easily extensible from the caller side, unlike having an actual lambda function that you can write however you need -- which may or may not be just adding a `!` at the beginning.